# Why doesn't Python raise an error on namespace collision?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-3.x

The following Python code executes normally without raising an exception:

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Foo:
    pass

def bar():
    pass

def bar():
    pass

print(Foo.__module__ + Foo.__name__)
```

Yet clearly, there are multiple instances of `__main__.Foo` and `__main__.bar`.  Why does Python not raise an error when it encounters this namespace collision?  And since it doesn't raise an error, what exactly is it doing?  Is the first class `__main__.Foo` replaced by the second class `__main__.Foo`?

Comment: to assign a variable twice is wrong?

Comment: But isn't it doing more than assigning a variable?  It's creating new types with each new class definition.

Comment: So what? It's creating the second class object, and then it assigns the name/"variable" `Foo` to refer to that class object instead of what it referred to previously. Modules are a sequence of statements (mostly like functions), and `class`/`def` are merely statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python everything is an object - instance of some type.  E.g. `1` is an instance of type `int`, `def foo(): pass` creates object `foo` which is an instance of type `function` (same for classes - objects, created by `class` statement are instances of type `type`).  Given this, there no difference (at the level of name binding mechanism) between

```
class Foo:
  string = "foo1"

class Foo:
  string = "foo2"
```

and

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

BTW, class definition may be performed using `type` function (yeah, there is type [`type`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#type-objects) and built-in function [`type`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type)):

```
Foo = type('Foo', (), {string: 'foo1'})
```

So classes and functions are not some different kind of data, although special syntax may be used for creating their instances.

See also related [Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) section.

Answer (score 1):

The second definition replaces the first one, as expected if you think at classes as elements in the "types dictionary" of the current namespace:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def test1(self):
...             print "test1"
... 
>>> Foo
<class __main__.Foo at 0x7fe8c6943650>
>>> class Foo:
...     def test2(self):
...             print "test2"
... 
>>> Foo
<class __main__.Foo at 0x7fe8c6943590>
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.test1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'test1'
>>> a.test2()
test2
>>>
```

here you can clearly see that the "definition" of `Foo` changes (`Foo` points to different classes in memory), and that it's the last one that prevails.

Answer (score 1):

The Foo class is effectively being re-defined further down the script (script is read by the interpreter from top to bottom).

```
class Foo:
  string = "foo1"

class Foo:
  string = "foo2"

f = Foo()
print f.string
```

prints "foo2"

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually this is just rebinding a name. It's no different from this:

```
x = 1
x = 2
```

and I'm sure you would not want that to be an error.

Answer (score 1):

In compiled and some interpreted languages there is a clear seperation between definition, declaration and execution. But in python it's simpler. There are just statements!

Python **EXECUTES** your script/program/module as soon as it is invoked. It may help, to see `def` and `class` as "syntactic sugar".  E.g. class is a convenient wrapper around `Foo = type("class-name", (bases), {attributes})`.

So python executes:

```
class Foo  #equivalent to: Foo = type("class-name", (bases), {attributes})
class Foo
def bar
def bar

print(Foo.__module__ + Foo.__name__)
```

which boils down to overwriting the names `Foo`and `bar` with the latest "declaration". So this just works as intended from a python-pov - but maybe not as you intended it! ;-)

so it's also a typical error for developers with a different background to misunderstand:

```
def some_method(default_list = []):
    ...
```

default_list is a singleton here. Every call to `some_method` usese the same `default_list`, because the list-object is created at first execution.

Python doesn't enter the function-body, but only executes the signature/head as soon as it begins parsing.